# Regex to find State and Zip from Address

Tags: regex

Trying to make regex that can get state from address

1- 1234 Bellaire Blvd, Suite 123, Houston, TX 77036

2- 1234 BELLAIRE BL #123, HOUSTON, TX  77036

I have this for state

> \w{2}(?=\s\d{1,5})

And this for Zip

> (?<=\w{2}\s)\d{5}

FOR STATE

In 1st case above regex is returning "te" from "Suite" and TX for state which is correct

However, in 2nd case it is returning nothing

FOR ZIP

77036 is returned in 1st case and null is returned in 2nd case

Answer (score 2):

I don't think regular expressions are the best way to do this. Rather I'd use an [API](https://smartystreets.com/docs/us-street-api) to parse the address into it's components. You will need state_abbreviation and you're sorted. Example response:

```
[
    {
        "input_index": 0,
        "candidate_index": 0,
        "delivery_line_1": "1 Santa Claus Ln",
        "last_line": "North Pole AK 99705-9901",
        "delivery_point_barcode": "997059901010",
        "components": {
            "primary_number": "1",
            "street_name": "Santa Claus",
            "street_suffix": "Ln",
            "city_name": "North Pole",
            "state_abbreviation": "AK",
            "zipcode": "99705",
            "plus4_code": "9901",
            "delivery_point": "01",
            "delivery_point_check_digit": "0"
        },
        "metadata": {
            "record_type": "S",
            "zip_type": "Standard",
            "county_fips": "02090",
            "county_name": "Fairbanks North Star",
            "carrier_route": "C004",
            "congressional_district": "AL",
            "rdi": "Commercial",
            "elot_sequence": "0001",
            "elot_sort": "A",
            "latitude": 64.75233,
            "longitude": -147.35297,
            "precision": "Zip8",
            "time_zone": "Alaska",
            "utc_offset": -9,
            "dst": true
        },
        "analysis": {
            "dpv_match_code": "Y",
            "dpv_footnotes": "AABB",
            "dpv_cmra": "N",
            "dpv_vacant": "N",
            "active": "Y",
            "footnotes": "L#"
        }
    },

    {
        "input_index": 1,
        "candidate_index": 0,
        "addressee": "Apple Inc",
        "delivery_line_1": "1 Infinite Loop",
        // truncated for brevity
    }
]
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can match against ', ([A-Z]{2}) ' the state will then be the subpattern matched by the parentheses. In python it would look like this.

```
import re

s1 = "1- 1234 Bellaire Blvd, Suite 123, Houston, TX 77036"

s2 = "2- 1234 BELLAIRE BL #123, HOUSTON, TX 77036"

m = re.search(', ([A-Z]{2}) ', s1)

print(m.group(1))
```